# Preventing loop inside useEffect with setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to fetch data when a state value changed.

This is easy approach since I can use `useEffect` and tell it to run when the state value changes. something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url,(result) => {
     // this is callback function when data fetched

  });

},[value]);
```

and somewhere in my render, I call `setValue` after the user clicks a button.

But in my situation, `value` has no default value so it's `undefined` the first time, My API provides the initial value for `value`. So the **first time** the `useEffect` must set `value` too.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url,({value, ...data}) => {
     // this is callback function when data fetched
     setData(data);
     setValue(value); // <- this line make loop since value is an object
    // But I need to set value for initial value that came from server
  });

},[value]);
```

And this makes an infinite loop since I'm changing `value` on effect which depends on value.

**In short**

1-I get my initial `value` from the API call

2-I need to re-call the API after the `value` is changed by user click.

These 2 condition makes an infinite loop, How I can approach this?

**UPDATED**

The value is an object that contains a year and month and its initial value is based on the user config in the database. It's something like `{month: 10, year: 2022}` and the user can change it in UI to navigate to other months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want to fetch something when value changes, I'd rather call it once, when user changes the `value` object.

```
function fetchValue(oldValue) {
  fetch(url, ({ value, ...data }) => {
    setData(data)
    setValue(value)
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
  // initial call to the API
  fetchValue()
}, [])

// Later...
<button onClick={() => {
  const newValue = updateValue(value)
  setValue(newValue)
  fetchValue(newValue)
}} />
```

or if you want to centralise effect handling with useEffect, you can split user-local value from what is returned from the server:

```
const [userValue, setUserValue] = useState()
const [serverValue, setServerValue] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url, ({ value, ...data }) => {
    setServerValue(value)
    setData(data)
  })
}, [userValue])

const actualValue = serverValue || userValue

<button onClick={() => {
  setServerValue(undefined)
  setUserValue(updateValue(actualValue))
}} />
```

Comment: In actuality, if you need to set the `value` only once, initially, from the server, I think checking for `value === undefined` (not fetchedValue as in answer by charchit) before setting it via `setValue` is a better solution.

Comment: Yes, but I need to change `value` based on user click too. that's why that answer is not working.

Comment: Still cause I need the initial value all the time, I mixed both solution, instead of `serverValue` I changed it to `initialValue` and only set it if `value` is undefined, and with some logic change its working now, I think the key in your answer is `const actualValue = serverValue || userValue` that's give me the idea to how should I right my logic

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is `undefined`. If it's not you can set its value.

Something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url,({fetchedvalue, ...data}) => {
     // this is callback function when data fetched
     setData(data);
     if (fetchedvalue == undefined){
          setValue(fetchedvalue); // <- this line make loop since value is an object
          // But I need to set value for initial value that came from server
     }
  });

},[value]);
```

Comment: Still, the first-time value is undefined, and when I call `setValue` it will run effect again. So in **the first time**, it calls API twice.